# Migrating from Drools 6.0.1 to Drools 6.3.0-Final got Unexpected global [log] error

Tags: java, drools

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected global [log]
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.setGlobal(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1163)
```

1. DRLs are retrieved from a database as list of Strings.
2. We dont use kmodule.xml
   ***Following the comments :***
   The DRL (minimized the setup to try and locate the issue) is loaded without a hitch but somehow the globals defined in it, are not .

KieSession creation code

```
 KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
        KieFileSystem kFileSystem = ks.newKieFileSystem();

        int i=0;
        for (String ruleId : drls.keySet()){
            Resource resource = ks.getResources().newByteArrayResource(drls.get(ruleId).getBytes());
            resource.setTargetPath("./out/"+ ruleId +".drl");
            resource.setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL);
            kFileSystem.write(resource);
        }
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder( kFileSystem );
        kieBuilder.buildAll();
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder( kFileSystem );
    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    if (kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
        log.error(PolicyUtils.createMsg("DRL Errors:\n" + kieBuilder.getResults().toString()), context, null, null);
        throw new RuntimeException("DRL Errors:\n" +         kieBuilder.getResults().toString());
    }
    kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());
    kContainer.newKieSession();
```

Comment: Are you validating that the KieBase you are creating doesn't contain any error? Just for completeness sake, could you post the following: the structure of where your DRL files are, your kmodule.xml and the code you are using to build your KieBase.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti So much time, mine and others', has been wasted due to sessions being created from an empty rulebase (whatever the reason) and people running in circles, chasing an error elsewhere. Why is there no exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your chat with @laune in the other answer, I guess that the problem is now identified: Your KieBase doesn't contain the artifacts (rules, globals, etc.) you think it does.

No idea what could be wrong with your code, but I think a simple workaround could save you from all that boilerplate (and error-prone) code you have there.

The idea here is to use the [`KieHelper`](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-knowledge/blob/6.3.x/kie-internal/src/main/java/org/kie/internal/utils/KieHelper.java) class instead of using `KieRepository`, `KieFileSystem` and `KieBuilder`. Actually, the `KieHelper` class was created to avoid this complicated steps (in comparison with Drools 5.x) involved in the creation of a KieBase.

Using the `KieHelper` class, you can refactor your code to look similar to this:

```
KieHelper kieHelper = new KieHelper();
for (String ruleId : drls.keySet()) {
    kieHelper.addContent(drls.get(ruleId), ResourceType.DRL);
}
Results results = kieHelper.verify();
for (Message message : results.getMessages()) {
    log.error(">> Message ({}): {}", message.getLevel(), message.getText());
}

if (results.hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("There are errors in the KB.");
}

KieSession ksession = kieHelper.build().newKieSession();
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

In your Java code you have some call like

```
kieSession.setGlobal( "log", ... );
```

which should have a counterpart in your .drl file such as

```
global ... log;
```

but it has not. (The dots mark the place for an object reference and the corresponding type, respectively.)

**Seeing your code...**

```
kFileSystem.write(resource);
```

I strongly recommend that you use the form with this relative path:

```
kFileSystem.write( "src/main/resources/" + ruleId + ".drl,
                   resource );
```

or modify the resource target path:

```
resource.setTargetPath("src/main/resources/hello.drl");
```

(Your code does *not* work:

```
resource.setTargetPath("./out/hello.drl");
```

Later, during compilation, this causes a warning "No files found for KieBase defaultKieBase". The Drools manual contains this sentence "These artifacts have to be added in the same position of a corresponding usual Maven project." but doesn't simply explain what this means, which would be much more helpful.)

Not having the "global" in your DRL code is, of course, equivalent to a failure to compile a knowledge base, i.e., your session is running on an empty knowledge base.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case as all the DRLs indeed have the global log variable  line + the same DRLs compile and work perfectly in Java 7 + Drools 6.0.1 (we just changed the version of Drools in Maven and compiled using Java 8 , no changes in DRLs or code )

Comment: Then you have failed to load your DRL code. Check for DRL compiler messages.

Comment: the output of kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages? or something else? thanks !

Comment: You do check for errors - OK! But see the extension of my answer.

Comment: Thanks ! Might this behave differently in the move from Drools 6.0.1 to 6.3 though ?

Comment: 6.0.x was the first stage after major changes, and not all may have been well in those versions. IIRC, the API for programmatically handling all the new Kie stuff wasn't even complete. All bets are off.

Comment: updated the Q with the findings that DRL is loaded OK, the globals aren't updated correclty though :/

Comment: Try *not* setting any globals. Add the "hello world" `rule x when then System.out.println("hi"); end`. Does it fire?

Comment: "not updated correctly": Do you mean that you still get the error "unexpected global [log]"?

Comment: I get the globals error + and if I remove setGlobals no rule is fired.

Comment: Then you are not loading a rule base. (Did you add the hello-rule?)

Comment: Yes, added it. All signs point to something in the loading being indeed off, but I can't figure out what .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106367/discussion-between-akapulko2020-and-laune).